# Is there a way to run programs using MapStruct without doing a maven clean install each time?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, mapstruct

Mapstruct generates a class after doing `mvn clean install`, but if it's not done, and I run my spring boot application I get a class not found exception. I was wondering if there was anything I can do to my Eclipse or add something in my pom.xml files (it's multiple projects so I need to do `mvn clean install` on each project first) so that Mapstruct generates the class when I just run my program normally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have the classes generated by the IDE you would need to set it up.

You can read more about Eclipse integration for MapStruct [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/#maven-integration).

In a nutshell you need to install the [m2e-apt](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-apt) plugin for Eclipse, which picks up and applies the annotation processor settings automatically.

You would also need to add the following to your `<properties>` in your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- automatically run annotation processors within the incremental compilation -->
<m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
```

Comment: I've done that and it still gives me a class not found exception when I run my spring boot application. Is there anything else I should be doing? Like running it as something else perhaps?